# Get Cell Value with column name in Php Excel

Tags: php, phpexcel

This is my excel sheet [image: Excel Sheet] it has got lots of columns but i'm breaking down for ease in understanding the question

I'm reading Excel Sheet using [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) and using rangeToArray() which give me  all row from excel but i want the output as

> Column as Key:Cell Value as Value

Currently I'm get output as

> Col Index :Cell Value

So my Question is which is that function in Php Excel which return array with Column name and it Cell value?

```
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file"'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
//  Get worksheet dimensions
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
$highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);
    printArr($rowData);
    printArr("-------");

}
```

I get output as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27745186
            [1] => 42058
            [2] => DELL INTERNATIONAL SERVICES INDIA PVT LTD
            ...
            ...
         )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 27745186
            [1] => 42058
            [2] => DELL INTERNATIONAL SERVICES INDIA PVT LTD
            ...
            ...
         )
)
```

Desire Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Invoice_no] => 27745186
            [Invoice Date] => 42058
            [Description] => DELL INTERNATIONAL SERVICES INDIA PVT LTD
            ...
            ...
         )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Invoice_no] => 27745186
            [Invoice Date] => 42058
            [Description] => DELL INTERNATIONAL SERVICES INDIA PVT LTD
            ...
            ...
         )
)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing magic in PHPExcel, but it's pretty easy to do in standard PHP

Retrieve the headings/keys that you want from the first row

```
$headings = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:' . $highestColumn . 1,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);
```

Then reset the standard numeric keys to be the headings values inside your reading loop for each data row

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);
    $rowData[0] = array_combine($headings[0], $rowData[0]);
}
```

Comment: i tried your solution i get an empty Array 
Array
(
    [0] => 
)

Comment: Then do some basic debugging..... show what you get back from `$rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);`.... because it isn't what you're showing in your question

Comment: when i print $rowData i get above array as shown above in question, which contain index value of column

Comment: Thanks for help i got it when i changed $heading to $heading[0]
$rowData[0] = array_combine($headings[0], $rowData[0]);

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that

Comment: I need one more help i want to use mysql_real_escape_string before fetching the cell value for security purpose becoz i'm inserting it in DB

Comment: You really should be using a modern DB interface like MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables, then you wouldn't need to escape anything.... but if you really have to use `mysql_real_escape_string` do `array_walk( $rowData[0], function (&$value) { $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value); } );` inside your loop

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($cell_collection as $cell) 
 {
 $column = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getColumn();
 $row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getRow();
 $data_value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($cell)->getValue();
 if ($row == 1) 
 {
    $header[$row][$column] = $data_value;
 } 
 else 
 {
    $arr_data[$row][$column] = $data_value;
 }
 }
```

Comment: you ll get rows and columns as you want

Answer (score 0):

I create this function for don't to write the title of reference like A1, A2, B1, B2. And works.

```
public function createExcel($titulos, $datos, $tituloLibro = 'The title')
{
    $phpExcelObject = //instance it;
    $phpExcelObject->getProperties()->setCreator("Your name")
        ->setLastModifiedBy("yourweb.com")
        ->setTitle($tituloLibro)
        ->setSubject($tituloLibro)
        ->setDescription($tituloLibro)
        ->setKeywords("")
        ->setCategory($tituloLibro);
    $i = 0;
    $phpExcelObject->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    foreach ($titulos as $titulo)
    {
        $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,1)->setValue($titulo);
        $i++;
    }
    $j = 2;
    foreach ($datos as $filas)
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($filas as $fila)
        {
            $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($i,$j)->setValue($fila);
            $i++;
        }
        $j++;
    }
    // your logic

}
```