# How to check if column headers are correct in PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm using the column header as an array index (row 1), and I don't want to have problems when they start uploading their XLSX file with incorrect column headers (or sometimes missing).

I found this answer really useful. I can make my array indexes as column headers:

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++){ 
    //  Read a row of data into an array
    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row,
                                            NULL,
                                            TRUE,
                                            FALSE);
    $rowData[0] = array_combine($headings[0], $rowData[0]);
}
```

> The code above is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32526911/8191721

Here's what I want to happen:

1. Check first the column headers if they matches with the column
   headers I provided (in array, so I can use `in_array` in a loop) before
   writing it to the database.
2. If the headers are correct, I will now turn the array indexes to column headers (so instead of `[0]`, it should now return `[firstname]`) or else throw an error message.
3. Write to database where the column names in my database exactly matches the column header names (or if not, at least matches the query) in their XLSX file. (I called them "column mapping").

Long story short, here's my code:

```
try {
    $inputFileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader     = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel   = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

    //-- Get worksheet dimensions
    $sheet         = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
    $highestRow    = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
    $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    $headings      = $sheet->rangeToArray('A1:'.$highestColumn.'1', NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

    //-- $row = 2 <- skip row 1 since this is our headers
    for($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
        //-- Read a row of data into an array
        $xlsxRow = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

        //-- Combine to replace indexes with header names
        $xlsxRow[0] = array_combine($headings[0], $xlsxRow[0]);

        //-- Got stucked in here..
        /*
          If column header fails, should exit the loop
        */

        //-- SQL query follows here..
}
```

So can someone help me figuring this out?

Comment: Did you mange to do the first part of it to match the headers with the array? Why do you want to change the header Indexes with the names? Instead write a function and get that value in a variable which you can use in the loop.i.e. `$firstName = $xlsxRow[0][0]`

Comment: Because I want to match the headers of Excel file with the headers in my database. So if in case the user changes the positions of the columns, the data will always and still correct. Example, First Name | Last Name. But I want to switch the position of First Name and Last Name. When he/she uploaded it in my interface, the data is still manageable and correctly inserted in their respective columns. Did you get what my point is?

Comment: So I just need to know how to check first the column headers. If one or more column is/are incorrect, then I have to cancel the query to avoid mismatch of information.

Comment: Use `array_diff ` to check if the headers passed and your array matches or not. If `false` display appropriate error. I still dont understand the need to change the index name. I had similar requirement and inside the for loop i assigned value to appropriate variable and used those variables in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To compare the header value you can use `array_diff()` function.

If you want to give more flexibility to user then you can use following example.
In this case use

```
$excelSheetHeaders = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 1; $i++) {

     $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $i . ':' . $highestColumn . $i, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

     $excelSheetHeaders = $rowData[0];

     $excelSheetHeaders = array_map('strtolower', $excelSheetHeaders);

     $errorCount = 0;

     foreach ($headerArray as $index => $value){

         if(!in_array(strtolower($value), $excelSheetHeaders)){
               $errorCount++;
         }

     }

     if($errorCount > 0){
         //Throw Error and exit;
     }

}

for ($i = 2; $i <= $highestRow; $i++){

    $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $i . ':' . $highestColumn . $i,NULL,TRUE,FALSE);

    $spreadsheetData = array();

    foreach($headerArray as $index => $value){

        $spreadsheetData[$value] = $rowData[0][array_search(strtolower($value),$excelSheetHeaders)];

    }

    var_dump($spreadsheetData);
}
```

This error is exactly what you want. Now you can access `$spreadsheetData['firstName']`.