# How to get selected dropdown value?

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to get value of cell which has dropdown selection. I tried this one:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("D7")->getCalculatedValue()
```

But I am getting only default one. Dataset for this dropdown select is in another page. How can I get selected value?

[Picture of dropdown selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsV8a.png)

It doesn`t matter which value I pick, I always get 'value1'.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Cell Value with column name in Php Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32526534/get-cell-value-with-column-name-in-php-excel)

Comment: No, it is not. I added link to picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a problem. I removed "getCalculatedValue()" and it works fine:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getCell("D7")
```